# Why do people use the 3cm M.K. 103 on the Luchs?

Tags: world-of-tanks

I often see people use that gun on the Luchs despite the L/60 so much better in nearly every aspect:

```
-----------------------------
|    Stat   |3cm M.K|5cm KwK|
-----------------------------
|Penetration| 95/110| 67/130|
|Damage     | 30    | 70    |
|RoF        | 22,5  | 28,6  |
|DpM        | 675   | 2002  |
|Aiming Time| 2,3   | 1,7   |
|Accuracy   | 0,46  | 0,39  |
|Weight     | 141   | 700   |
-----------------------------
```

As you can see the only stat which is better for the 3cm is the Weight which hardly makes any difference in my experience since the engine of the Luchs is rather strong.

Tazilon (who is writing scouting guides) suggests t use the 3cm but I don't understand why and he does not tell people why the 3cm is better. In my experience the burst of the 3cm is unspectacular (180). You can only kill a (very) low level arty with that burst if you are lucky whicle the L/60 spews out a whopping 500 damage while the 3cm reloads. If the target is far the 3cm is inaccurate while the L/60 is rather accurate and in close quarters you can easily circle any tank so the burst does not make a difference.

So all in all: what are the reasons for a Luchs player to use the 3cm?

Please note that I only load APCR ammo + HE ammo to maximize efficiency.

Comment: The penetration difference (~30 at close range) is probably the main reason. The weight difference will only make you get at top speed earlier. I'm don't play scouts a lot, I'm a sniper kinda tanker.

Comment: [Here some opinions](http://forum.worldoftanksxbox360edition.com/index.php?/topic/34138-luchs-5-cm-kwk-39-l60-vs-3-cm-mk-103/) on each guns. The 3cm is a 10 round auto-cannon.

Answer (score 4):

As seen [here](http://wiki.wargaming.net/en/Tank:PzII_Luchs); note the fixed table with all 3 Ammo Types:

```
-----------------------------------------------
| Stat                  | 3cm M.K  | 5cm KwK  |
-----------------------------------------------
|Penetration(AP/APCR/HE)| 95/110/15| 67/130/25|
|Damage(AP/APCR/HE)     | 30/30/40 | 70/70/90 |
|RoF (RpM)              |   0.22   |    24    |
|Aiming Time            |   0.22   |    2.3   |
|Weight                 |    141   |    700   |
----------------------------------------------
```

I conclude that people choose the 3cm with AP because it has a better Armor penetration; which could potentially be more useful in a wider variety of situations than a low penetration HE shot.

As far as i can read, the 3cm is also an auto-cannon, which could provide higher burst damage and/or better performance when shot while driving.

Answer (score 1):

the first turret has faster traverse which is good when you entrap an enemy vehicle in your circle of death.  the first turret can hold a 30mm but not a 50mm

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the 5cm L/60 is much better. The Mk103 does not have the range and the accuracy/spread of a burst is terrible. And if penning is an issue one can always resort to APCR.

Answer (score -2):

I play it with the 3cm because of the troll factor. You can one clip your own tier and do dmg to higher tiers tanks.

it is very powerful in a 3 luchs platoon when you do a drive-by and empty 3 clips at once